# Running python code from ruby with variables

Tags: python, json, ruby, python-3.x

I am running python scripts from ruby. But I have pass parameters to python script that i cam from ruby. The parameters that should be passed is the some variable i have in that particular instance. Here is my code that illustrate the scenario.

```
    #test.rb
    result = `python ml.py '{"a":1, "b":23, "c":2334,"d":2244}'`
```

The code above works perfectly. But the params are generated from some manipulation which i need to pass to the python script. Sending the params is the issue for me. Here is the code I implemented.

```
     #testvar.rb          
     params = manipulate_data              # This gives result in json format
     #result `python ml.py 'params'`        # Not working
```

I tried other approach as well but not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ cat d.py
import json
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict
print json.loads(sys.argv[1], object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
$ cat a.rb
require 'json'
params = {"a":1, "b":23, "c":2334,"d":2244}.to_json
result = `python d.py '#{params}'`
puts result
$ ruby a.rb
OrderedDict([(u'a', 1), (u'b', 23), (u'c', 2334), (u'd', 2244)])
```